# How do you map the "shift + space bar" keystroke command in the Lynx browser?

Tags: configuration, browser, lynx

I've been reading through documentation and sample configurations of the Lynx text-based browser to learn how to map a key to a command in Lynx. I learned that the space bar key can be used to page down, which is similar to the behavior in most major browsers such as Chrome. See the following link.

http://web.mit.edu/cygwin/cygwin_v1.3.2/usr/share/lynx_help/keystrokes/keystroke_help.html

I would like to map the "shift + space bar" keystroke to copy the page up behavior in Lynx. I found the syntax to map a key in a CFG file is: `KEYMAP:<KEYSTROKE>:<LYNX FUNCTION>`. See the following link.

https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx2.8.3/breakout/lynx.cfg

I also learned that the caret symbol "^" represents the Control key. For example, `KEYMAP:^A:HOME` maps Ctrl-A to the Home command in Lynx, which moves the cursor to the top of the page. However, I don't see any examples of mapping the shift key. How do you map the "shift + space bar" keystroke command in the Lynx browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't (because unless you're able to (re)configure the keyboard, terminals won't send a distinct set of characters for <kbd>*Shift*</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>).

Beyond that, `lynx` doesn't have a special feature for mapping key-modifiers since that's too terminal-specific to have been standardized.  Lynx's [`KEYMAP`](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#KEYMAP) feature uses a subset of the standard terminfo capabilities.